# ArcGis SDK VS2010 folder empty

Tags: visual-studio-2010, arcgis

I installed Esri's SDK for 2010 and authorized it.  Now when I open Visual Studio 2010 -> New Project -> I see a directory labeled "ArcGis" in the C# section, and this directory has three subdirectories {Desktop Add-Ins, Extending ArcObjs, Server Obj Ext}, but each of these directories is empty.  I've never used this SDK before, but I assume that it didn't install properly because of the empty directories.  Has anyone seen this issue?  Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open a new project you have the option of using .NET 3.5 or .NET 4.0, in order to view these add-ins, you must select .NET 3.5.  FYI